# how to do client side validation for AsyncFileUpload in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, validation, file-upload, asynchronous, jquery-validate

I tried the validator with file upload and it works fine but for AsyncFileUpload i get a error

```
Control 'AsyncFileUpload1' referenced by the ControlToValidate 
         property of 'RegularExpressionValidator1' cannot be validated.
```

is there any method by which I can do validation before uploading the file. Thanks

```
   <asp:AsyncFileUpload ID="AsyncFileUpload1" runat="server" UploadingBackColor="Yellow"
        OnUploadedComplete="ProcessUpload" OnClientUploadComplete="showUploadConfirmation"
        ThrobberID="spanUploading" />
     <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Only zip file is allowed!"
        ValidationExpression="^.+(.zip|.ZIP)$" ControlToValidate="AsyncFileUpload1"> </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Comment: Try this  http://forums.asp.net/p/1545760/3777877.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I doubt whether with **[Async File Upload](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AsyncFileUpload/AsyncFileUpload.aspx)** you can do this, as it will check at **[OnUploadedComplete](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/HOW%20TO%20Use%20the%20AsyncFileUpload%20Control.ashx)** at server side and **[OnClientUploadComplete](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/HOW%20TO%20Use%20the%20AsyncFileUpload%20Control.ashx)** at client side.

So my conclusion is that it may not be possible.

**[check this link for more info](http://weblogs.asp.net/manojkdotnet/archive/2009/10/16/asynfileupload-control-and-its-validation.aspx)**

**[Alternative approach](http://www.dotnetjalps.com/2011/12/async-file-upload-with-jquery-and.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a%20blogspot/DotNetJalps%20%28DotNetJalps%29&utm_content=Google%20Reader)**